# Activeadmin - Associated model name with field name returning "uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am using `activeadmin - 1.2.1`, `activeadmin_addons - 1.1.2` and `rails 5.1`. I want to filter based on associated model field name so I have written a filter:

```
filter :customer_client_id,
  as: :search_select_filter,
  url: proc { customer_index_path },
  fields: %i[key name],
  display_name: 'name',
  minimum_input_length: 2,
  order_by: 'name_asc',
  label: 'Customers'
```

`:customer_client_id` where `Customer` is model name and `client_id` is field name, this works perfect if I use select but if I use `search_select_filter` I am getting error `"uninitialized constant"`. Can anyone help me fixing this issue?

Comment: What constant is uninitialized? This seems like the crux of your question yet you left it out of the error message.

Comment: :customer_client_id is associated column name so its unable to filter with that column. customer is associated table name and client_id is column name. if i use as: :select association works but if i use as: :search_select_filter its not working.